# Multiply two arrays and find the summation of the result

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3]] 
y = [[0, 1, 5], [2, 4, 6],[4, 5, 6]]
```

how to multiply all the elements in y array  by each element in  x  array      and  find the summation of the result  as below:

```
 1*0 + 1*1+ 1*5    2*0 + 2*1+ 2*5     3*0 + 3*1+ 3*5
 1*2 + 1*4+ 1*6    2*2 + 2*4+ 2*6     3*2 + 3*4+ 3*6
 1*4 + 1*5+ 1*6    2*4 + 2*5+ 2*6     3*4 + 3*5+ 3*6
```

Comment: I can't tell what your expected result is. A 3*3 matrix?

Comment: Yes, it supposed to be a 3*3 matrix

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [numpy.ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). With NumPy arrays, you can easily multiply them using `numpy.multiply(x1, x2)`, where `x1` and `x2` are NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.matrix([[1,2,3]]*3).transpose()
y = np.matrix([[0, 1, 5],[2, 4, 6],[4, 5, 6]]).transpose()   
z = (x*y).transpose()
```

x:

```
[[1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]]
```

y:

```
[[0 2 4]
 [1 4 5]
 [5 6 6]]
```

z:

```
[[ 6 12 18]
 [12 24 36]
 [15 30 45]]
```